# Inverse Kendall's Tau

Tags: statistics

I am required to compute the inverse of Kendall's Tau to compute a corresponding copula parameter. Kendall's Tau is defined as

tau = (no. of concordant pairs - no. of discordant pairs)/(n(n-1)/2).

I currently have a dataset of 100 observations on the interval [-1,1] (these are the correlations, according to Kendall's Tau). How can I take the inverse of these, according to Kendall's Tau? The issue is that unlike an equation f(x) where you can rearrange to find x, this question doesn't have a main variable, hence I'm unsure of what I actually need to calculate.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What mathematical model are you referring to exactly (there is Kendall's rank correlation coefficient, but I feel this is not what you mean). What do you want to calculate? What have you tried? Where are you hitting a wall?

Comment: i've edited the question slightly, i hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Kendall rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient)
Tau is defined as

```
tau = (number of concordant pairs) - (number of discordant pairs)
      -----------------------------------------------------------
               (total number of pairs)
```

If we let N be the total number of pairs, C be the number of concordant pairs and D the number of discordant pairs. We have

```
tau = ( C - D ) / N
N = C + D
```

N is known its just n (n-1) / 2 in this case 100 * 99 /2 = 4950.

Rearrange the first equation to get

```
N * tau = C - D
N = C + D
```

Add to get

```
N * ( 1 + tau) = 2 * C
```

subtract the first from the second to get

```
N * ( 1 - tau) = 2 * D
```

so the number of concordant/discordant pairs is easy to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Ok but is this known as the inverse of Kendall's Tau? I have looked at papers where the inverse of Kendall's Tau is assumed to be easily calculated, but it is unclear to me which element should be seen as the inverse of kendall's tau, because it's not an equation f(x) where you can just rearrange to find x

Comment: Strictly speeking Kendall's Tau is a function on the complete list of pairs. That is a function from an n*2 dimensional space. You can meaningfully recover the inverse as there are many sets of data which would have the same coefficient. The function does not have a well defined inverse as its not 1 to 1. All we can do is find the number of concordant/discordant pairs.